# "No such interface supported" using Visual Studio 2015 Diagnostic Tools

Tags: visual-studio, azure, visual-studio-2015, debug-diagnostic-tool

I'm trying to use **Visual Studio 2015 Diagnostic Tools** but when I open the Windows this message appears:

```
The diagnostic tools failed unexpectedly.
```

[image]

Then I review the *output window* and configure output for ***Diagnostics Hub*** then I Found

```
No such interface supported
No such interface supported
```

- I'm currently running a managed console application. Consuming an azure website REST api
- Visual Studio Enterprise 2015 Update 1 14.0.24720.00

Why I'm getting this error?
How Can I resolve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently is a problem with an update of Windows, the upgrade process does not take into account or  modifies erroneously a file that interfere with the operation of the Diagnostic Tools window.

The solution -*though there is supposed to  later version of Visual Studio will delete those files*- is follow these instructions:

1. Close Visual Studio.
2. Open an Administrator Command Prompt
3. Enter the following commands:

```bash
cd %systemroot%\system32

takeown /f DiagnosticsHub.*

icacls DiagnosticsHub.* /grant %username%:F

del /q DiagnosticsHub.*
```

Now should restart Visual Studio.

For more info click [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2015/07/24/no-such-interface-supported-in-visual-studio-2015-on-windows-10.aspx)